# How to set default remote ref in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, push, gerrit, git-push, tortoisegit

How can I change default remote ref for TortoiseGit push dialog? It is normally `master`. I can change it to `refs/for/master` always when I push from combo or keyboard and it works, but I would like to stay the ref of my choice there. How can I do this?

[image: TortoiseGit push dialog]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that the checkbox "Always push to the selected remote branch for this local branch" should do this.

Answer (score 5):

For me the accepted answer did not work.  Instead I went to the Remote settings and selected "Push default" on the default remote item (as shown below).

[image]